# Is there an algebraic formula that gives this weird multiplication?: $(-x)\circ(-x)=(-x)\circ(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I'd like to know whether it's possible to give an equivalent algebraic formula, in terms of normal algebraic operations (i.e. $+, -, ×, ÷, x^y$), if possible avoiding $|x|$, for an operator $\circ$, in the domain ℤ such that:

\begin{array}{|r | r r r r | r r r | r r r r}
\hline
\circ & ... & -4 & -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & ... \\ \hline
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu\raise12mu{.} \\
-4 & ... & -16 & -12 & -8 & -1 & 0 & -4 & -8 & -12 & -16 & ... \\
-3 & ... & -12 & -9 & -6 & -1 & 0 & -3 & -6 & -9 & -12 & ... \\
-2 & ... & -8 & -6 & -4 & -1 & 0 & -2 & -4 & -6 & -8 & ... \\ \hline
-1 & ... & -4 & -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & -1 & -2 & -3 & -4 & ... \\
0 & ... & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... \\
1 & ... & -4 & -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & ... \\ \hline
2 & ... & -8 & -6 & -4 & -2 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & ... \\
3 & ... & -12 & -9 & -6 & -3 & 0 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & ... \\
4 & ... & -16 & -12 & -8 & -4 & 0 & 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & ... \\
\vdots & \kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu\raise12mu{.} & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{array}

As you see, this is some sort of weird multiplication where $(-)\cdot(-)=(-)\cdot(+)=(+)\cdot(-)=(-)$ but $(+)\cdot(+)=(+)$. I am mostly interested in the subcase of the square in the middle and, if possible, all the $\circ$ operations where at least one of $-1$, $0$ or $1$ is an argument. If that operation can satisfy at least the square at the middle, that will be enough for me. As a last resort I'm disposed to accept division by zero defined in such a way that for all $x$, $x/0=0$.

But it is important to note that, even if it doesn't matter too much what happens outside the domain $\{-1, 0, 1\}$, the operation must be defined for all integers: no modules, no restricted domains.

If that isn't possible, what strategy shall I use to prove it?

ps: Since I'm not a mathematician, I'd like to apologise for any formal or conceptual error I've made. Corrections, though, are more than encouraged.

Comment: "If that operation can satisfy at least the square at the middle, that will be enough for me." $$x\circ y=xy\cdot\cfrac{1+x+y-xy}2$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check it right now!

Comment: Just want to say that this is a really cool question, and well formatted as well. I hope to see it answered well!

Comment: Cool! As far as $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ is concerned, your operation does it it! Thanks again Rahul. And thank you too Brevan.

Comment: your multiplication can be written as $\text{sign}[\min(a,b)] |ab|$. Now note that $\min(a,b) = \frac{a+b-|a-b|}{2}$ and that $|a-b| = \sqrt{(a-b)^2}$. I just don't know how to generally represent $\text{sign}(a,b)$ in a form like you desire, and already I am pushing the line a bit by utilizing $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: It would seem that this works, but it requires $x/0 = 0$. It does use division though - I don't know how to avoid that: $$\frac{\sqrt{\left(a+b-\sqrt{\left(a-b\right)^2}\right)^2}}{a+b-\sqrt{\left(a-b\right)^2}}\sqrt{a^2b^2}$$

Comment: Waw! That was really cool! Well, I'm interested in this operation because I need some kind of $weird$ $exponentiation$ such that $(-1)^n=-1$, $0^n=0$, and $1^n=1$.

Comment: @LuisBartolo Is there a particular reason you want to avoid divisions and absolute values? I would still argue that $\text{sign}[\min(a,b)] |ab|$ is a much simpler definition, and that in many cases a piecewise definition would be even better

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen. Division because it is always preferable to avoid the problem of division by 0. But if it can be formulated without diving by 0, it's all well. (I think I'm going to change that in my entry.) About absolute values, I always found those operations to be somewhat spurious. (Please, don't ask me why, :p)

Comment: It is an important thing to note, though. 'How to define this operation?' - _you just did_. It's really, really important not to confuse _formulas_ for _definitions_. It may be worth asking 'is there an algebraic formula that gives this operation?' Or even 'how close can this operation be to multiplication?' (For starters: it looks like it defines a monoid, but clearly it can't be invertible). But the way you've phrased the question is IMHO actually a bad habit that it's worth trying to shed.

Comment: Thanks, @StevenStadnicki. I did some modifications to the wording of the questions. I hope that way is better.

Comment: You asked for a binary law  $*:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ but you define $*$ only on the diagonal, i.e. $(-x)*(-x)=(-x)*(x)$. I think it would be better if you ask about a function such that its restriction to the diagonal satisfies your operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid using the absolute value and sign functions if you change the representation of the domain! Let's use a sign-and-magnitude construction. An integer is a pair $(\sigma, n)$ where $\sigma$ is either the symbol $+$ or the symbol $-$, $n$ is an natural number, and we identify $(+,0)=(-,0)$. For a natural number $n$, we *may* use the shorthand $n=(+,n)$ and $-n=(-,n)$. But whenever we want to define any operation on integers, we may choose to define the operation on the sign and the magnitude independently; and the operation will be well-defined as long as we respect $(+,0)=(-,0)$.

With that setup, the definition is just:
$$(\sigma,x)\circ(\tau,y)=(\min(\sigma,\tau),xy)$$
Then observe that if either $x=0$ or $y=0$, then $xy=0$, so the sign doesn't matter, and we're done.

If you're unhappy with the $\min$ function, we can do away with that too, by representing the sign *symbol* as a sign *bit*. The usual computer representation would be $0=+$ and $1=-$. But it's slightly better for us to choose the opposite, $0=-$ and $1=+$. Then we have:
$$(\sigma,x)\circ(\tau,y)=(\sigma\tau,xy)$$
which is as simple as you could hope for!